# What do I do when I have an unknown stale connection with Tokeet when linking rentals?

Tags: icalendar

I have unknown ical connection within Tokeet and not in another channel. The connection has gone stale. My URL's are correct and the connection has suddenly gone stale. How can I resolve this and restore my connection?

Answer (score 0):

While Unknown stale connections are rare within Tokeet, the easiest way to resolve it is to delete the original export and import connections and proceed by completing all the steps in the attached set up guide.

[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wvW16q3kamXp_GoZmBExiUPZrobvUbBbcGdfJHLAZRc/edit?usp=sharing]